# Orthogonal complement of an complex subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

Let V = $C^3$ and let $W = \text{sp} ([1, 0, i], [i, 1, 0])$.

(a) Find $W^⊥$

(b) Extend the spanning set for W into a basis for $C^3$

(c) Let $W = \text{sp}(a_1, a_2, \cdots , a_k)$ be a $k$–dimensional subspace of $C^n$. Give the formula for
the projection matrix that gives the orthogonal projection from $C^n$
to $W$.

-My questions-

For a  do we just find the null space of the matrix formed by the vectors?

b) how would one extend the spanning set of W to a basis for $C^3$?
Do we add the three elementary vectors and row reduce?

(c)is it $P=A(A^TA)^{-1} A^T$ = $A(A^*A)^{-1} A^*$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are given that $W=\DeclareMathOperator{Span}{Span}\Span\{v_1,v_2\}$ where
\begin{align*}
  v_1 &= \langle 1,0,i\rangle & v_2 &= \langle i,1,0\rangle
\end{align*}

$(a)$ To find $W^\perp$, first note that the equation
$$
A
\begin{bmatrix}
  1\\ -i\\i
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
  0\\0\\0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
implies that $\Span\{v_3\}\subseteq W^\perp$. Since 
$$
\dim W^\perp=\dim\Bbb C^3-\dim W=3-2=1
$$
we have $W^\perp\subseteq\Span\{v_3\}$. Hence $W^\perp=\Span\{v_3\}$.

$(b)$
Now, since $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ are linearly independent in $\Bbb C^3$ and
$\dim\Bbb C^3=3$, we have that $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ is a basis for $\Bbb C^3$.

$(c)$ This formula is correct.